# Компиляция через gcc

Tags: c++, bat, gcc

Как мне при компиляции .dll через gcc в выходных файлах скомпилировать .lib файл? Если я компилирую через clang, тогда он мне выдает как .dll, так и .lib

build.bat:

```
REM Build script for engine
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Get a list of all the .c files.
SET cFilenames=
FOR /R %%f in (*.cpp) do (
    SET cFilenames=!cFilenames! %%f
)

REM echo "Files:" %cFilenames%

SET assembly=engine
SET compilerFlags=-g -Wvarargs -Wall -Werror
REM -Wall -Werror
SET includeFlags=-Isrc 
SET linkerFlags=-luser32 
SET defines=-D_DEBUG  -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

ECHO "Building %assembly%%..."
g++ %cFilenames% %compilerFlags% -o ../bin/%assembly%.dll %defines% %includeFlags% %linkerFlags%
```

Comment: .lib файлы обычно использует линкер vc++

Comment: @user7860670 то есть, через gcc не получится?

Comment: Через gcc это обычно и не нужно. В Visual Studio все равно не получится использовать C++ библиотеку, собранную gcc.

Comment: lib-файлы - это архивы объектных модулей, которые присоединяются линкером к финальному экзешнику. Их формат, ровно как и формат самих объектных модулей, зависит от конкретного пакета компилятора. Соответственно, lib-файлы, созданные в GCC могут быть потом использованы только в GCC, но не в MS VC++. И наоборот. Для сборки lib-файлов в пакет GCC входит отдельная утилита ar. В MS VC++ этим линкер вроде бы занимается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC использует для статических библиотек расширение `.a`, а не `.lib`.

Что вам выдает Clang - вообще неважно. Он может работать как в режиме совместимости с GCC, так и с MSVC - смотря как настроите.

Чтобы собрать статическую библиотеку, делаете:

- `g++ 1.cpp -c` - получаете `1.o`
- `ar -rcs lib1.a 1.o` - получаете `lib1.a` - саму библиотеку.

  До этого возможно стоит стереть старый файл, потому что иначе `ar` дописывает объектники в уже существующий файл. (Добавляет новые и перезаписывает старые, но ничего не удаляет - вроде так.)

  Префикс `lib...` в имени файла очень рекомендуется, потому что потом, когда будете подключать либу через флаг `-l??`, этот префикс будет добавлен к имени автоматически...

Чтобы собрать динамическую библиотеку, делаете:

- `g++ 1.cpp -c` - получаете `1.o`
- `g++ 1.o -shared -o lib1.dll` - получаете `lib1.dll`.

  Современный MinGW умеет линковаться напрямую с `.dll`. Если у вас какая-то старая версия, то к последней команде надо добавить `-Wl,--out-implib=lib1.dll.a`, чтобы потом, при линковке с библиотекой указывать этот свежесозданный `lib1.dll.a`, а не `.dll` (тоже флагом `-l1`, `lib??.dll.a` дописывается автоматически).

Еще, батники - сомнительный выбор. Уж лучше потратьте время на изучение Make или CMake, тогда будет (относительно) кросс-платформенно.

И вот это в мусор: `-D_DEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Это имеет только смысл для стандартной библиотеки MSVC, у GCC она своя.